# Is there a way of getting current sprint number in azure cli?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, command-line-interface

I would like to automate create ticket from the cli, at the moment I need to adapt the iteration to the current sprint, Is there a way to get the current iteration from the cli?

```
az boards work-item create --title "myticket" --type "task" --assigned-to "myusername" --iteration "myorg\XX\Sprint YY" --area "myorg\myteam"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, use the command [az boards iteration team list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/boards/iteration/team?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_boards_iteration_team_list) with the `timeframe` option set to `current`

```
az boards iteration team list --team myteam --timeframe current
```

Please note that you also need to pass the team name as different teams may have different sprints as the current sprint.